# C++ autocomplete for dependent types

Tags: c++, intellisense, c++-concepts, using-declaration

I'm using gcc-13 and VSCode with intellisense. It does a good job with typed auto complete of members and functions.

```cpp
template <typename State>
concept IsPerfectInfoState = requires(
    State obj,
    typename State::Types::VectorAction &vec,
    typename State::Types::PRNG &device) {
    {
        obj.terminal
    } -> std::same_as<bool &>;
    {
        obj.row_actions
    } -> std::same_as<typename State::Types::VectorAction &>;
    {
        obj.col_actions
    } -> std::same_as<typename State::Types::VectorAction &>;
    {
        obj.payoff
    } -> std::same_as<typename State::Types::Value &>;
    {
        obj.obs
    } -> std::same_as<typename State::Types::Observation &>;
    {
        obj.prob
    } -> std::same_as<typename State::Types::Probability &>;
    {
        obj.apply_actions(
            typename State::Types::Action{},
            typename State::Types::Action{})
    } -> std::same_as<void>;
    {
        obj.get_actions()
    } -> std::same_as<void>;
} && IsState<State>;
```

The above asserts members like `terminal` and methods `apply_actions` exist. The last `&&` statement even lets autocomplete work with the  requirements of `IsState`.

I also want to assert the existence of  typenames or using declarations so that `SomeClassWithRealType::R`    will autocomplete the `::Real`, the same way something like this will fill in the `T`:

```
struct Foo {
    using T = int;
};
```

I know you can assert a type is valid

```
template <typename State>

    concept HasType = requires () {
    typename State::T;

};
```

But this doesn't work with autocomplete.

Comment: Hard to auto-complete `T` which is already a complete name ;-)

Comment: lol. I'm not convinced this is possible so I opened a feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/11266